# Python: efficient method to replace accents (é to e), remove [^a-zA-Z\d\s], and lower()

Tags: python, regex

Using Python 3.3. I want to do the following:

- replace special alphabetical characters such as e acute (é) and o
  circumflex (ô) with the base character (ô to o, for example)
- remove all characters except alphanumeric and spaces in between alphanumeric
  characters
- convert to lowercase

This is what I have so far:

```
mystring_modified = mystring.replace('\u00E9', 'e').replace('\u00F4', 'o').lower()
alphnumspace = re.compile(r"[^a-zA-Z\d\s]")
mystring_modified = alphnumspace.sub('', mystring_modified)
```

How can I improve this? Efficiency is a big concern, especially since I am currently performing the operations inside a loop:

```
# Pseudocode
for mystring in myfile:
    mystring_modified = # operations described above
    mylist.append(mystring_modified)
```

The files in question are about 200,000 characters each.

Comment: I cannot post an answer cause this question is wrongly marked as duplicate, which absolutely isn't, but maybe I'll manage to put my answer in a comment. Provided `from unidecode import unidecode`, the job will be accomplished by `''.join(c for c in unidecode(mystring).lower() if ord(c) in range(97,123) or ord(c)==32).lstrip().rstrip()`. No regex needed.

Answer (score 34):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> s='éô'
>>> ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
'eo'
```

Also check out [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode)

> What Unidecode provides is a middle road: function unidecode() takes
>   Unicode data and tries to represent it in ASCII characters (i.e., the
>   universally displayable characters between 0x00 and 0x7F), where the
>   compromises taken when mapping between two character sets are chosen
>   to be near what a human with a US keyboard would choose.
>
> The quality of resulting ASCII representation varies. For languages of
>   western origin it should be between perfect and good. On the other
>   hand transliteration (i.e., conveying, in Roman letters, the
>   pronunciation expressed by the text in some other writing system) of
>   languages like Chinese, Japanese or Korean is a very complex issue and
>   this library does not even attempt to address it. It draws the line at
>   context-free character-by-character mapping. So a good rule of thumb
>   is that the further the script you are transliterating is from Latin
>   alphabet, the worse the transliteration will be.
>
> Note that this module generally produces better results than simply
>   stripping accents from characters (which can be done in Python with
>   built-in functions). It is based on hand-tuned character mappings that
>   for example also contain ASCII approximations for symbols and
>   non-Latin alphabets.

Comment: This works nicely for removing accents but unless I did something wrong it doesn't seem to address the other aspects of the question. Appreciate the introduction to Unidecode. An interesting read, though it wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: its also working def remove_accents(data):
        return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', data).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')

Comment: @RanvijaySachan What's the difference?

Comment: I don't understand why the `if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'` condition changes the output from accented-character to unaccented?

Comment: I don't think this is completely correct. It does normalize accents, but it also removes all non-english characters entirely. If a sentence contains greek letters like `θ`, those get removed entirely.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [str.translate](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
import collections
import string

table = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)
table.update({
    ord('é'):'e',
    ord('ô'):'o',
    ord(' '):' ',
    ord('\N{NO-BREAK SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{EN SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{EM SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{THREE-PER-EM SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{FOUR-PER-EM SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{SIX-PER-EM SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{FIGURE SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{PUNCTUATION SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{THIN SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{HAIR SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{IDEOGRAPHIC HALF FILL SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE}'): ' ',
    ord('\N{TAG SPACE}'): ' ',
    })
table.update(dict(zip(map(ord,string.ascii_uppercase), string.ascii_lowercase)))
table.update(dict(zip(map(ord,string.ascii_lowercase), string.ascii_lowercase)))
table.update(dict(zip(map(ord,string.digits), string.digits)))

print('123 fôé BAR҉'.translate(table,))
```

yields

```
123 foe bar
```

---

On the down-side, you'll have to list all the special accented characters that you wish to translate. @gnibbler's method requires less coding.

On the up-side, the `str.translate` method should be fairly fast and it can handle all your requirements (downcasing, deleting and removing accents) in one function call once the `table` is set up.

---

By the way, a file with 200K characters is not very large. So it would be more efficient to read the entire file into a single `str`, then translate it in one function call.

Comment: Performance seems identical to my approach (0.96875 seconds in both cases), but this is much less hackish. Thanks. With respect to translating the entire file at once, I need to preserve the text formatting because I'm working with data files such as csv.